# Passing Parameters to ReportView using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, reportviewer

Everything ok? 
I have a mission today, I never did something like this before.
Well...
I have a ReportView in my Project:

See him Codebehind:

```
private Customers GetData()
        {
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCBRConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("STP_REL_SUSTENTABILIDADE");
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ANO", "2014"));
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CONS_TP_INDICE_ID", "1"));
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@INDICADOR", "C"));
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UNIDADE", "1"));
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UNIDADE_ADM", "1"));
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ENDERECO", "8"));
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TIPO_MEDIDORES", "1"));
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MEDIDORES", "93"));

                    using (Customers dsCustomers = new Customers())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dsCustomers, "DataTable1");
                        return dsCustomers;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

paying attention until here, you'll see the Parameters called by GetData:
ANO, CONS_TP_INDICE_ID, INDICADOR, UNIDADE, UNIDADE_ADM, ENDERECO, TIPO_MEDIDORES AND MEDIDORES.

At Stored Procedure has this same parameters, but at table (sql) don't have ANO and INDICADOR.

When I execute the Project don't show me the parameters from GetData and I don't know how I input the two parameters ANO , INDICADO to bring results.
The Report comes empty, but running the Stored Procedure bring me 1 result sucessfull.

What has Wrong?

Comment: Can you show your `STP_REL_SUSTENTABILIDADE` definition?

Comment: Sorry @SonerGönül, but I can't cause the STP_REL_SUSTENTABILIDADE has 126 lines. It's bigger and she do INNER JOIN to others 3 tables from sql.

Comment: Your Class Customers... is this of type Dataset? If so, are you sure there is a table in that instance of dsCustomers with name "DataTable1"?  Have you hardcoded the column names of that table?  If so, did you include the ANO and INDICADOR?

Comment: @DiscipleMichael 
Steps that I doing:
1 - Creating Report
2 - Select the Data Source
3 - In Data Source - Select the STP_REL_SUSTENTABILIDADE
4 - Selecting the Arrange Fields
(CONS_TP_INDICE_ID, INDICADOR, UNIDADE, UNIDADE_ADM, ENDERECO, TIPO_MEDIDORES AND MEDIDORES)

Until here, everything ok, but Missing ANO and INDICADOR.

When I running directly from DataSource the STP_REL_SUSTENTABILIDADE, comes values sucessfull.

I don't know what I do more :(

Comment: Hi Guys! I inputed manually values in Stored Procedure to bring a positive result... just for test. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have finished

1. Create Extension Method

   public static void View(this ReportViewer ReportViewer, DataTable TableName, string DatasetName, string pathReport, params ReportParameter[] reportParameters)
   {
   ReportDataSource SourceReport = new ReportDataSource(DatasetName, TableName);
   ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = pathReport;
   ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(SourceReport);
   ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(SourceReport);
   if (reportParameters != null)
   {
   ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters.ToArray());
   }
   ReportViewer.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout);

   ```
    }
   ```

then Load Report
reportViewer1.View(Table, String Dattaset, "pathReport",new ReportParameter("Para","value"));